# When using \textsc, LaTeX issues warning: Font shape `OT1/cmr/bx/sc' undefined

Tags: fonts, bold, small-caps

I started to write my CV in LaTeX. My document begins as

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{amsart}
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
\usepackage[finnish]{babel}
\begin{document}
\begin{center}
{\large \textbf{\textsc{ANSIOLUETTELO}}}
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

But pdfTeX for Mac says:

```
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.1415926-1.40.11 (TeX Live 2010)
....
LaTeX Font Warning: Font shape `OT1/cmr/bx/sc' undefined
(Font)              using `OT1/cmr/bx/n' instead on input line 6.

[1{/usr/local/texlive/2010/texmf-var/fonts/map/pdftex/updmap/pdftex.map}]
[2] (./ansioluettelomod.aux)
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You're doing nothing wrong: the font family doesn't have a small caps boldface variant. However, capital letters in small caps are just the normal ones.

Comment: OK. So is there some way to modify the line such that it uses normal letters, not small caps?

Comment: in fact, you're using all caps; to get small caps (when they exist) you should use lowercase, as `\textsc{ansioluettelo}`.  if you're happy with ordinary caps here, just remove the `\textsc` and you'll get regular bold caps and no warning message.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You can try

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{amsart}
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}   
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}   
\usepackage[finnish]{babel}
\begin{document}
\begin{center}
{\large \textbf{\textsc{ANSIOLUETTELO}}}

\textbf{\textsc{Ansioluettelo}}
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Capital letters in the argument of `\textsc` don't produce small caps.

Comment: Fix the problem, but that font has ugly aliasing.

Comment: Any fix for the Aliasing problem?

Answer (score 9):

You did nothing wrong.  TeX tells you that it does not have Small Caps bold Computer Modern font, so it switches to bold normal font.  This is a design decision by font author (Knuth) not to have this variant;  you may try to find fonts that have bold small caps (not that I know of such) or to fake the effect using uppercase.

Actually your line is already in uppercase, so I wonder whether you really need small caps: usually people use small caps with lowercase letters, with `\textsc{\MakeLowercase{...}}`

Answer (score 8):

The [libertine](http://ctan.org/pkg/libertine) font provides bold small caps. Abstaining from capital letters in the argument of `\textsc` doesn't hurt, either. ;-)

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{libertine}

\begin{document}

\Large

\textbf{\textsc{Ansioluettelo}}% right

\textbf{\textsc{ANSIOLUETTELO}}% wrong

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: If using debian-like distro, you should `apt install texlive-fonts-extra` to get this font.

Answer (score 5):

If you do not want to change the fonts scheme, you can do

```
\DeclareFontShape{OT1}{cmr}{bx}{sc}{<-> cmbcsc10}{}
```

Answer (score 2):

use the `Kepler fonts` they have bold small caps:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{amsart}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{kpfonts}
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
\usepackage[finnish]{babel}
\begin{document}

{\large \textbf{\textsc{ANSIOLUETTELO}}}

\end{document}
```